# Large size file upload without changing php.ini

Tags: php, file-upload, zend-framework2, chunks, chunked

I created chunk file using jquery slice function

```
var chunk = blob.slice(start, end);
```

and append this chunk to new formData

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('fileToUpload', blobFile);
```

and send this blob to upload.php file. But i getting only the $_file contain
Array

```
(
    [fileToUpload] => Array
        (
            [name] => blob
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 1
            [size] => 0
        )

)
```

.
My requirement is upload large file into server and i am using file operation for append the received contents to file. My problem is i am not getting the what i passed from jquery and what i get is string "blob". How can i chunked file upload without using plugins.

Answer (score 0):

There is one error triggered. error =  1 means post_max_size error and I reduced the chunk size. The problem solved and now its works perfect and i can upload large file without any packet loss.